# Climbing cost per mountain

Tags: data-request, sports

I am looking for a data set listing the [cost](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65756/1810) of climbing a mountain, with as many following fields as possible:

- mountain name
- location
- climbing time
- price breakdown (insurance, porters, etc.)

Comment: point 4 (price breakdown) is the kind of information that has to be manually collected and curated.